Mapping all the fields of an DTO object from different stream resultset (different database results) in Java
I have a ItemDTO object and some of the fields have data from BigQuery database and few of it from the DB2 database. I want to retrieve both the data and merge to the DTO object using streams, but it's not as expected.
BigQuery table includes data as:

DB2 table data:

Expected result : merge of all the fields:

I used streams to perform the merge:
public static class ItemDTO {

        String itemNumber;
        String itemName;
        int postcode;
        String location;
        String price;

        //getter & setters 
    }

List<ItemDTO> bigQueryResults = //resultset from BigQueryDB
/*Retrieved bigquery results: [{
"itemNumber":"101"
"Name":"chair"
"Postcode":"4513"
"Location":null
"Price":null
},
{
"itemNumber":"102"
"Name":"Table"
"Postcode":"2341"
"Location":null
"Price":null
}]*/


List<ItemDTO> db2Results = //resultset from DB2
/*Retrieved db2 results: [{
"itemNumber":"102"
"Name":null
"Postcode":null
"Location":"New York"
"Price":"120"
},
{
"itemNumber":"101"
"Name":null
"Postcode":null
"Location":"Amsterdam"
"Price":"250"
}]*/

// retrieving a list of combined results from both db2 and BQ with key as itemNumber
 List<ItemDTO> resultList = db2List.stream()
                .filter(a -> bqList.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getItem_nbr().equals(a.getItem_nbr())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

/* Expected Output: [{
"itemNumber":"101"
"Name":"chair"
"Postcode":"4513"
"Location":"Amsterdam"
"Price":"250"
},
{
"itemNumber":"102"
"Name":"Table"
"Postcode":"2341"
"Location":"New York"
"Price":"120"
}]*/

/* ResultList output: [{
"itemNumber":"101"
"Name":"chair"
"Postcode":"4513"
"Location":null
"Price":null
},
{
"itemNumber":"102"
"Name":"Table"
"Postcode":"2341"
"Location":null
"Price":null
}]*/



But when i use this , the i am getting the rows with only mapped values for BigQuery fields. The fileds present in DB2 are populating as null.
Please let me know is there any other way to handle this kind of mapping. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

When asking questions like this it helps to post a [mre].  At a minimum, you should provide the DTO class,  sample data properly shown in Java, and expected output, properly formatted.  Please check out [ask] and take the time to take the [tour].

You also need to show samples of what's in the lists you are streaming.  Remember that other folks will search this site looking for solutions to similar questions.  That information will make it clear as to what is going on.

I'm sorry,  but posting images doesn't help (and is really frowned upon in SO).  Just show the lists populated with instances of the data., eg bigQueryResults = List.of(new ItemDTO(...), new IdemDTO(...)...)

@WJS Updated the code with sample outputs. and result list

This will merge all partial db extractions with the same ItemNumber.

This first creates a map from bigq using the item number as the key
then via collectingAndThen, post processes that map, streaming dbq
for all Items with the same id, the location and price are set from the dbq item.

The class definition
class ItemDTO {

    String itemNumber;
    String itemName;
    int postcode;
    String location;
    String price;

    public ItemDTO(String itemNumber, String itemName, int postcode,
            String location, String price) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.location = location;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(int postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return itemNumber + ", " + itemName + ", " + postcode + ", " + location
                + ", " + price;
    }

}

The process
List<ItemDTO> bigQueryResults = List.of(
        new ItemDTO("101", "chair", 4513, null, null),
        new ItemDTO("102", "Table", 2341, null, null),
        new ItemDTO("103", "Television", 5607, null, null),
        new ItemDTO("104", "Microwave", 2378, null, null),
        new ItemDTO("105", "Sofa", 1278, null, null));

List<ItemDTO> dbQueryResults = List.of(
        new ItemDTO("102", null, 0, "New York", "120"),
        new ItemDTO("106", null, 0, "Budapest", "300"),
        new ItemDTO("101", null, 0, "Amsterdam", "250)"));

// retrieving the db2 results for itemNumbers from bigQueryResults
List<ItemDTO> mergedResult = bigQueryResults.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
           Collectors.groupingBy(ItemDTO::getItemNumber),
           mp -> dbQueryResults.stream().<ItemDTO>mapMulti((item, consumer) -> {
               List<ItemDTO> sameNumberList = mp.get(item.getItemNumber());
               if (sameNumberList != null) { // item number may not be
                                             // in map  
                  for (ItemDTO i : sameNumberList) {
                    i.setLocation(item.getLocation());
                    i.setPrice(item.getPrice());
                    consumer.accept(i); // put updated item on stream
                  }
               }
          }))).toList();

mergedResult.forEach(System.out::println);

prints the following for the provided data
102, Table, 2341, New York, 120
101, chair, 4513, Amsterdam, 250)

Recommend you look at mapMulti, CollectingAndThen, Collectors.groupingBy
Updated answer for Java-8.

first groupBy as before
then iterate over the two lists and adding the modified ItemDTO to the merged results list.

Map<String, List<ItemDTO>> mapByItemNumber = bigQueryResults.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemDTO::getItemNumber));

List<ItemDTO> mergedResults = new ArrayList<>();

for (ItemDTO item : dbQueryResults) {
    if (mapByItemNumber.containsKey(item.getItemNumber())) {
        for (ItemDTO i : mapByItemNumber.get(item.getItemNumber())) {
            i.setLocation(item.getLocation());
            i.setPrice(item.getPrice());
            mergedResults.add(i);
        }
    }
}

mergedResults.forEach(System.out::println);


Thanks for the response. But I am using Java 8

@sharonm Did you see my updated answer?  It works for Java-8.
